# How to remove the TimeZone from a TimeObject

Tags: date-and-time

`TimeObject` constructor adds `TimeZone` even when it's not meaningful or appropriate.

In this  example, *Mathematica* imputes `GMT-7` because I'm in California. But the data represents sensor clock w/ only HMS data (no location).

```
TimeObject[{0, 15, 14}] // FullForm
```

> ```
> TimeObject[List[0, 15, 14.`], Rule[TimeZone, -7.`]]
> ```

Standard replacement doesn't hold:

```
TimeObject[List[0, 15, 14.2`], Rule[TimeZone, -7.`]] /. Rule[TimeZone, _] :> Sequence[]
```

[image]

A similar problem (is it worth a separate question?): `TimelinePlot` also imputes today's YMD date visible on mouseover. This is false as the sensor was recorded months ago:

```
 TimeObject[{0, 15, 14}] // TimelinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: In 10.0.2 under Windows `TimeObject[{0, 15, 14}] // FullForm` is simply ``TimeObject[List[0, 15, 14.`]]``.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In it's current form `TimeObject` always refers to a specific moment in time with an explicit `TimeZone` value.  An alternative representation for what you have, in terms of HMS without any local/timezone would be a `MixedRadixQuantity` representing a duration since midnight:

`MixedRadixQuantity[{0, 15, 14}, {"Hours", "Minutes", "Seconds"}]`

Though this is not a form supported in `TimelinePlot` at the moment.

Comment: The imputed `TimeZone` is a real problem, as data could come from, say, devices or data collection points across time zones, ie be wrong.