# How to prevent TimeSeries adding TimeObject parameter and TimeZone option to DateObjects?

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

`TimeSeries` adds a `TimeObject` parameter and a `TimeZone` option to `DateObjects`.  How can this be prevented?

`DateObjects` are created without either of `TimeObject` or `TimeZone`.

```
dat = {DateObject@{2007, 1, #}, #} & /@ Range[2]
```

[image]

---

## Version 11

Things were slightly improved in version 11.  The `"Dates"` property now has the dates without the polluted `TimeObject`.

```
ts = TimeSeries[dat];
ts["Dates"] // InputForm

(* {DateObject[{2007, 1, 1}], DateObject[{2007, 1, 2}]} *)
```

However, the `"FirstDate"` and `"LastDate"` properties still have the `TimeObject` pollution.

```
ts /@ {"FirstDate", "LastDate"} // InputForm

(* {DateObject[{2007, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -3.], TimeZone -> -3.],
    DateObject[{2007, 1, 2}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -3.], TimeZone -> -3.] } *)
```

My fingers are crossed for 11.1

---

## Version 10.4.1

When loaded into a `TimeSeries` `DateObjects` are polluted with these addtions.

```
ts = TimeSeries[dat];
ts["Dates"]
```

[image]

The *extras* can be see from `InputForm`.

```
ts["FirstDate"] // InputForm
(* DateObject[{2007, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0.}, TimeZone -> -3.], TimeZone -> -3.] *)
```

How can this be turned off?

Comment: It may be difficult to turn this off. What problem does this behavior cause? Perhaps those are easier to solve.

Comment: @MarcoB The issue is comparison with dates in the code. All dates in the code do not have the extra bits in them.  So wherever I compare dates with the polluted `TimeSeries` dates I do not get equality.

Comment: You could consider writing a custom equality test based on `DateDifference[]` if need be.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78901/how-to-remove-the-timezone-from-a-timeobject

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way to prevent the addition, so you might be left with cleaning up after the fact.

Depending on which side you control, you could either add the missing bits, or remove the excess.

If you want to add the missing parts:

```
datComplete = {DateObject[{2007, 1, #}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0}], 
                  TimeZone -> $TimeZone], #} & /@ Range[2]
```

[image: complete dates]

Alternatively, if you want to clean up the output of `TimeSeries`:

```
Clear[cleanDates]
cleanDates[date_DateObject] :=
  ReplaceAll[
    date,
    DateObject[{y_, m_, d_}, ___] :> DateObject[{y, m, d}]
  ]
SetAttributes[cleanDates, Listable]

ts["Dates"]
cleanDates@ts["Dates"]
```

[image: the original]
[image: cleaned up]

Comment: Yes. I capitulated to the cleaning scenario shortly after posting as work needed to continue. (1+)  I don't get why WRI is added things it. It is very annoying to slap all that bloat into your data with no way of preventing it. An odd choice.

Comment: @Edmund It certainly is! My best guess is that it has to do with the fact that interpolation will be used to fill in missing values, but still... More importantly, I'm unpleasantly surprised that the comparison fails! I'd expect that, when a comparison is called for, the missing parts in your simpler `DateObjects` would be filled in with appropriate default values, just like `TimeSeries` does! That's the unsettling bit, in my opinion. I'd otherwise be OK with the added bits, if the comparison to a simpler structure still worked automagically...